# How to pass instance of one Bloc instance to another bloc , so that we can use BlocA state change in BlocB

Tags: flutter, bloc

How do pass an instance of one Bloc instance to another bloc, so that we can use BlocA state change in BlocB

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically just pass it as a parameter. But you shouldn't. It is not recommended by the author of Flutter Bloc.

The recommended solution is to let blocs communicate via either the presentation layer (the UI) by using BlocListeners, OR via streams from injected repositories.

There is a segment on this in the documentation:
https://bloclibrary.dev/#/architecture?id=bloc-to-bloc-communication